# Beautifulsoup find_all returns TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, error-handling, web-scraping

This should have an easy solution but I can't understand how to avoid it.

```
    content1 = soup.find('div', class_='fusion-text fusion-text-6')
    content2 = soup.find('div', class_='fusion-text fusion-text-7')

    for para in content1:
        comp_name = para.find_all('a')['href']
        print(comp_name)
```

The error comes because I have a list at `['href']` together with `find_all`.

```
        comp_name = para.find('a')['href']
```

doesn't return an error and gives the right output (an URL), but just the first one. Since I want to scrape all of them inside my `content1` I wanted to use `find_all` but inevitably I get the error.

How can I avoid this?

Thank you.

Comment: if the result is a list, you can access list elements like mylist[0] and you can pull out elements from 0 to len(mylist)

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure if I understood it. How can I access it if it returns an error? I don't know how to create a list out of find_all. Thanks.

Comment: comp_name = para.find_all('a')[0].get('href') or
comp_name = para.find('a')['href']    return 1 result, but I can't get all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions:

```py
comp_name = [link['href'] for link in para.find_all('a')]
```

Comment: thanks, it works but I can't get the text, only html. I tried .text but as usual find_all doesn't accept that.

Comment: @Steven, change `link['href']` to `link.get_text()` to get the text

Comment: alright, thanks. Just a note, with that from url-html I get the other text at the end of the tag and not urls anymore

Answer (score 1):

This will give you list of companies then you need an other loop/or list comprehension to extract from the children.

```
 for para in content1:
    comp_name = para.find_all('a')
    all_comps = [one_para.get("href") for one_para in para]
    print(all_comps )
```

Comment: this is a copy of my answer :(

Comment: @Nauman thanks, I kinda get what you wrote but I get this:  
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get'